# Function notation for the equation of a plane

Tags: calculus, notation

> Recall that the equation of a plane is given by $ a x+b y+c z=d $ or
> if we solve this for $z$ we can write it in terms of function
> notation. This gives, $ f(x, y)=A x+B y+D $

Solving for $z$ gives $z=\frac{d-ax-by}{c}$. So how do you go from this to $ f(x, y)=A x+B y+D $? Since the letters are capitals in the second equation I assume they are different variables. Where did $c$ go?

Comment: As $z=f(x,y)$: $A=-a/c, \ \ B=-b/c, \ \ D=d/c$. Where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the constants $A,B,C$ are allocated corresponding to the variables $x,y,z$. Now,

$$z= \frac{d-ax-by}{c} = \frac{-a}{c}x+\frac{-b}{c}y+\frac{d}{c}$$

Letting $A = \frac{-a}{c}, B = \frac{-b}{c}, D = \frac{d}{c}$, you get

$$z = Ax+By +D$$

It's purely conventional, you can name the constants whichever way you want.